Outlook Update May 2024: Direct Click on Network Share Links Inoperative Without “Open Link” Right-Click
I’ve recently encountered an issue with NEW Microsoft Outlook where hyperlinks in emails no longer open with a direct click. Instead, a new option appears on right-click called “open link,” which does work. However, I prefer the convenience of the single-click functionality.
This seems to be a recent change, and I’m looking for a way to restore the previous behavior. Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, could you provide a solution to revert to the direct click to open links?

Based on my testing, there is no reproduction of your issue. It is possible to hold down Ctrl and then click on the link.

holding Ctrl makes no difference. How did you test? In my new outlook, link appears like that: https://outlook.office.com/local/path/file://myServer/folder/xxxx.txt

Is it the link itself? Can't open all the other links?

all web links work. Link to local files work as described just on right click + warning notice

Based on my search, here's a thread where the link can't be opened, you can refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1494455/unable-to-links

Can you add a screenshot of the right-click menu and warning notice? For example, Classic Outlook has a similar security warning when you open a file:// link to a server that isn't explicitly trusted: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-blocks-opening-fqdn-and-ip-address-hyperlinks-after-installing-protections-for-microsoft-outlook-security-feature-bypass-vulnerability-released-july-11-2023-4a5160b4-76d0-465b-9809-60837bbd35a8
